# How to create two objects of the same class but with different data with factory_girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I would like to create 2 records using factory_girl.
One would be fruits and the second vegetables. How can I do that? 
I know that I can make one like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
    title ''
  end
end
```

Also should I run create or something for the data to be saved?
I have tried two ways. Both gave an error.

First

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
    title 'fruits'
    title 'vegetables'
  end
end
```

Second

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
    title 'fruits'
  end
  factory :category do
    title 'vegetables'
  end
end
```

Comment: Please add to your question what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth I have updated the question with what i have tried.

Comment: Have you read the [Getting Started documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md)? If not, start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

factory_girl allows you to override the data (or lack thereof) in a factory definition. You can define your factory like this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category
end
```

and use it like this in a spec:

```
create :category, title: 'fruits'
create :category, title: 'vegetables'
```

Alternatively, you could define two different factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :fruits_category do
    title 'fruits'
  end
  factory :vegetables_category do
    title 'vegetables'
  end
end
```

and use them like

```
create :fruits_category
create :vegetables_category
```

Only put data in a factory that the user would expect from the factory name, so that tests are easy to understand.

Comment: There's a lot more to it :) Well worth reading through the whole documentation so you know what is available.

Comment: Ok let me correct myself, now I understand the basics :)